# Prove that "injective function $f:X\to Y$ exists" and "surjective function $g:Y\to X$ exists" is logically equivalent.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that

- injective function $f:X\to Y$ exists
- surjective function $g:Y\to X$ exists

is equivalent.$(x,y\neq \emptyset)$

**My approach**

First,prove left to right.

If injective function $f:X\to Y$ exists, a set A can be defined like this.
$$A=\{f(x):x\in X\}$$
then it is sure that $A\subset Y$, and $|A|=|X|$

And, if we define function $g$ like
$$g(y)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if $y\in A$ and } f(x)=y,\\x_0& \text{if }y\notin A.\end{cases}$$
($x_0$ is a fixed element of $X$)

Then, $g$ is a surjective function, so surjective function $g:Y\to X$ exists.

Now,prove right to left.

If surjective function $g:Y\to X$ exists, $\forall x \in X$, we can select a element $y\in Y$ that $g(y)=x$, which is clear that we can pick a different $y\in Y$ for $\forall x \in X$

if we define function $f$ as $f(x)=\text{one element in Y that g(that element)=$x$}$, f is a injective function, so injective function $f:X\to Y$ exists.

---

But, I am not sure that my approach is right, especially on proving right to left.
Please check whether my approach is right, ways to improve it,  and some other ways of proving this question.

Comment: FWIW you may refer to $A$ directly as $f(X)$.  For a function $f:X\to Y$ and any $K \subset X$ we usually have defined "the image of $K$ under $f$" notated as $f(K)$ as $f(K) :=\{f(x)|x\in K\}$.

Comment: How does your left-to-right proof work if $X$ is the empty set?

Comment: If you assume that $X$ is nonempty, then the two statements are **equivalent**, that is, they are equivalent in standard set theory with the axiom of choice included. They are not **logically** equivalent! What made you think they are logically equivalent? What did you mean by "logically" equivalent??

Comment: Two formulas are logically equivalent means we can prove the equivalence of two formulas without any assumption, including axioms of set theory. That is, we call two formulas are logically equivalent only when their equivalence follows from the logic itself, and not based on any additional hypotheses.

Comment: Also, the standard notation for the size of sets is $|A|$. $n(A)$ is widely used in Korean textbooks (and maybe Japanese ones, especially that for middle- and high school students.) But I have not seen this notation outside of secondary textbooks.

Comment: @bof I forgot to say that $X,Y\neq \emptyset$

I edited the question that way.

Comment: And about equivalent and  logically equivalent,
I think I chose the wrong word, since I am a foreign language speaker.
Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @HanulJeon Well... I am a Korean Middle school student.
Thank you for pointing it out.
I will edit my question that way.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation - especially for $g$. It seems like you are missing the word "if" before your condition - it's really hard to parse just a bunch of commas because that makes it difficult to see what the value is and what the condition is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct but you have to quote Axiom of Choice for  right-to-left implication.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Note that this proposition is equivalent to proving that a function has left inverse iff it is one-one and a function has right inverse iff it is onto.